# Is this really the sort of answer we as a community want on our site?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

I don't believe that [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/87366/are-there-any-valid-reasons-for-disallowing-characters-and-limiting-the-length-of/87367#87367) is of any use on the site:

> ## No
>
> There are no *good* reasons,

That's it. No further explanation or justification of this view. It doesn't add anything to the debate. Yet as of this writing it has a score of 17 consisting of 26 up-votes and 9 down-votes.

If we as a community want this site to be taken seriously we all have to act responsibly and show that we (that's everyone who contributes to the site) know what we're talking about.

NOTE: I'm not singling out any particular user here, nor am I questioning the validity of the actual answer - just that there's no *evidence* to back up the bald assertion.

Comment: Probably worth reminding folks that these are the sorts of answers that'll send a question crashing through the floor when it comes time to hold up [the subjective guidelines](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). Short, no why/how, no references... So if you want to see a question closed, by all means vote these answers to the top...

Comment: When you say *we want*, are you talking about moderators/site owners or the community?

Comment: @Pierre - the "we" was meant to be the community. I did make the question community wiki to try and reflect that, but that seems to have been reverted by someone.

Comment: @ChrisF: sorry Chris, another question before I contribute: *if we want this site to be taken seriously*, by whom you want to be taken seriously?

Comment: @Pierre - 1) people who use Google (or Bing...) to search for the sort of questions we ask and get Programmers as the top links. These people (at the moment) no nothing about us and we want their first impressions to be good. 2) Stack Overflow users who at the moment migrate their rubbish should be able to look at this site and think "ah I won't migrate this question as it's not a good fit for Programmers either".

Comment: Another way of looking at this though might be that it is working. The answer is technically correct which is what people are up voting (currently +34) but the 16 down votes it also has are a pretty good indication that it could and should be better. Part of the problem is that there (still) isn't a really great answer to the question there...

Comment: @Pierre: Stack Overflow was able to attract a lot of brilliant and in some cases high-profile members of the software community. Surely these people have something to contribute on the "subjective" side as well, and yet we don't see them participating here much. I don't speak for everyone, but that is definitely what ***I*** mean when I talk about not being taken seriously. This ought to be the type of site where we might reasonably expect to see the likes of Fowler or Beck. I'm not seeing that; in fact I don't think I've seen any A-listers post here. Needs improvement.

Comment: @Aaronaught: I see some value in having a-players here like Fowler. But this shouldn't be our primary objective. Our primary objective should be providing useful information to normal programmers, the vast majority of us. You would be surprised by the number of them that don't care about Fowler or Beck. They just get things done, the right way, with a smile ;)

Comment: @Pierre: I never said that was our goal. I said that was our litmus test. If none of these people see fit to give us the time of day (and I'm quite sure that at least *some* of them know we exist) then it's a good sign that perhaps we aren't delivering the practical value that some of us might think.

Comment: @Aaronaught: that's your personal opinion or the output of discussions with other community members? Looks like a biased thinking to me (cognitive bias). FYI, I explain the absence of those a-players simply by the lack of time & interest, not the quality of answers/questions.

Comment: @Aaronaught - to be fair, I think the reason most of those people achieve things of note is that they don't spend time on places like this... I do agree with Pierre though, while it would be great to have people like that on here, for the most part I'm more interested in opinions of people who spend their working lives in similar situations to the ones I face.

Comment: @Pierre: Then how do you explain their *presence* on other sites, especially Stack Overflow?  Why would people like Eric Lippert, Jon Skeet, and Alex Martelli waste their time there? *(P.S. The phrase "cognitive bias" in parentheses adds nothing in terms of clarity or credibility.)*

Comment: Sorry, @Jon, but I don't agree. I'm not suggesting that the site should be *crawling* with them, but the fact that not a *single* one of them ever seems to have even taken notice is telling. I can understand that with some of the non-programming SEs - they are all starting from zero credibility in their field - but this site is riding the coattails of Stack Overflow for page views which means it *should* be doing roughly the same in terms of reputation (the real kind of reputation, not the numeric kind).

Comment: @Aaronaught - I honestly don't understand why you think (a) that they would come here and (b) whether it's a big deal whether they do or don't. Most questions on this site are pretty trivial, basic stuff people are helping each out with. If you want to see Kent Beck and David Heinemeier Hansson arguing the toss over things then I think you're in the wrong place rather than this place being wrong. Besides, if you make a large chunk of your living as an author and public speaker as many of these people do, why would you come some place to give your content away for free?

Comment: @Aaronaught: **Overgeneralization** – *Taking isolated cases and using them to make wide generalizations*. Real *active* a-players in SO are rare. So if you compare SO population (683K) to P.SE (27K)...

Comment: **Fortune telling** – *Exaggerating how things will turn out before they happen.* If we look serious, a-players will come to us. **Mind reading** – *Assuming special knowledge of the intentions or thoughts of others.*. a-players are looking for elite places because they are elites.

Comment: @Pierre: Here you are engaging in the exact same behaviour that this very question is decrying; putting **pithy phrases** in **bold letters**, then adding a *vague explanation* and acting as though you've made a *forceful point*. It's like reading a form letter from a PR/Marketing firm. If you have something important to say, please put some effort into it and stop being so condescending.

Comment: @Jon: These people already put loads of free content on their blogs, so I don't buy the money angle at all. And I didn't say I wanted to see anybody "arguing the toss", just making an occasional contribution - hell, making a *single* contribution would be swell. The whole *point* of Stack Exchange is to draw in experts, to replace the success of Stack Overflow. True that not every "expert" is necessarily an A-lister but don't you think we should be seeing the occasional, fleeting post from one or two?

Comment: @Aaronaught: oh sorry if I looked condescending. I didn't meant to. The objective was really to demonstrate what a cognitive bias was.

Comment: @Pierre: I know what a cognitive bias is. Pointing out what you perceive to be a bias does not logically imply (a) that you are any less biased, or (b) that it is actually wrong. We have historical evidence from Stack Overflow, Math Overflow, and other "high-level" SE-based sites to indicate that keeping the quality level high does in fact attract notable experts. Disproving that this applies more broadly would require some reasonable counterexamples.

Comment: @Aaronaught: Sorry if you took this personally. I'm not immune to cognitive bias. Nobody is. I would be more than happy to read about the proof you are talking about.

Comment: Do we really want the sort of people on our site who demand that you write a novel when saying one or 2 words would suffice.

Comment: @Aaronaught for the record - [Bob Martin has posted 18 answers here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/is-this-really-uncle-bob)

Answer (score 16):

There's a subtle but pernicious problem with the quoted answer and many like it: *it's impossible to prove a negative.*

This kind of answer would never fly on any of the science SE sites because it is incorrect *by definition*.  The best *objective* answer one can give (assuming one agrees with the "no" premise) is to list the reasons that *might* be considered valid and explain why they should be considered invalid.  If no such reasons are known, then the correct answer to the question isn't *"no"*, it's actually *"I don't know"*, which clearly isn't worth posting as an answer.  Maybe a comment, if the question goes [tumbleweed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges/21/tumbleweed).

I don't know if we should be trying to "moderate away" these answers, but [as I've pleaded for in the past](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1400/3249), we desperately need people to start downvoting these fact-free "pithy phrase" answers instead of upvoting them.  I think that having answers on top of the heap that look like they took 5 seconds to poop out (maybe less) really hurt our credibility as a community.

Stack Exchange wants to [optimize for pearls, not sand](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).  *Part* of this is emphasizing the value of great answers.  The other part is *de-emphasizing the poor ones*.  This is exactly why we have downvotes.  Has anyone *ever* seen a 1-line answer singled out in a positive light on the SE blog, or on any major blog, or really anywhere other than maybe reddit?  *Some* short answers may genuinely be correct and complete, but *most* of them are... sand.

Please, for the love of all that is holy, stop pressing the other arrow when you see this type of pandering.

Comment: @Aaronaught: for the record, it took far less than 5 seconds to poop out the answer. Is there a badge for that?

Comment: @Steven - You want a badge for not really making much of an effort?

Comment: @Jon: No, but I would like a badge for having a sense of humor.

Comment: I agree with you but I think its a waste of time to try and influence the way the community will vote...you may as well argue with the tide that it doesn't need to come any further in.

Comment: Many people just upvote for the big bold letters and some italics here and there. This fumes me up.

Comment: Hence the titling of the voting-buttons. It is NOT correct and incorrect, it says “useful” and “not useful”. This perfectly illustrates the target of voting, but does not seem to be clear enough to (some) voters.

Answer (score 15):

## No

This is *not* the sort of answer that we want on our site.

Comment: And you got some votes out of this just for big bold letters and italics here and there.

Comment: @Marcelo: _judicious_ use of bold and italics for emphasis can be quite effective

Comment: I *see*. <-- I'm pretty bad at it.

Comment: If you didn't post this answer, I was gonna do it :)

Answer (score 4):

I've been noticing a trend towards more and more answers that folks *want* to be true, even when real-life experience states the opposite. [Example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86502/move-on-and-look-elsewhere-or-confront-the-boss), where "run away" is the most common of answer.

Comment: To her credit, the author of the highest voted answer did edit it to not suck... eventually.  Too bad most of the votes came *before*.

Comment: As the person who posted the second most popular answer, I was actually pleasantly surprised that about a third of people saw constructive engagement as the way forward. I think that the problem isn't to do with this site, is a problem with the attitude and sense of absoluteness that many programmers have.

Comment: +1 This, absolutely, completely, 100% this.

Comment: @Jon: For me it's kind of hard to distinguish the "site" from the "community" - the attitude you speak of is most definitely the root of the problem, and it is a pervasive one in this community. There are, as evidenced by some of the dialogue in the linked thread and even by this meta thread, a *lot* of members who want to see a bit more substance, but I still feel like we're outnumbered by the me-tooers.

Comment: @Aaronaught - I was talking about all programmers everywhere, rather than just the subset who come here who I think are generally better and more enlightened than average. While the internet has made us all aware of what a great working environment looks like or what good practice is, it hasn't put it into context that most places and situations are a long way from ideal and that people need to constructively engage to improve things rather than just asserting them. I see blunt answers as having the same fundamental route - asserting not engaging, what's right not what's practical.

Comment: This is a dangerous path to tread; if this community wants to be a community for discussion and not just cut-and-dried answers, sometimes the practical answer is **wrong**, even if it might be the only choice at a given time.  You **should** run from a terrible company; whether you can do it immediately or have to take the time to find another job first is what is subjective, not the fact you need to leave.

Answer (score 3):

IMO it really depends on the question. A question that provokes such an answer is probably not a good one. For example, if someone asked "Are there good reasons to assume that Microsoft will abandon Windows in favor of Linux?", it would be pretty hard to give a much better answer.

Comment: In that case should you really be answering the question at all? Sorry if this sounds harsh, but that case you should be voting to close as not constructive/not a real question rather than answering.

Comment: ChrisF: I tend to agree with you, but real-life question might be less obviously stupid than my hypothetical example.

Comment: What you're referring to is speculation, which is already expressly prohibited across the entire network.  In this case, I don't think that the question was stupid, and *some* of the answers do provide insight. A lot of things sound stupidly obvious when you've only ever been exposed to one side of the issue; if you take the time to explain your perspective then that's completely OK, but if you declare it as **the truth**, *end of conversation*, then you're doing everybody (including yourself) a disservice.

Comment: @ChrisF - Great point.  In addition, it really irks me when a tough question is answered with the first thing that comes to mind by several people who don't really know enough to give a *good* answer -- rather than waiting for someone qualified to answer.  Which is another reason why downvotes are so important.

Comment: Aaronaught: when I wrote my answer and the comment above, I hadn't learned about the original question yet; that's why my answer contains a bit of speculation.

Comment: Even with that hypothetical question you can give good reasons WHY Microsoft won’t do it.

Answer (score 3):

The community is clear. That answer got more upvotes than downvotes, therefore you have your answer.

However here is my opinion: I don't think it's good to have short answers unless the short answer covers it all. Which is pretty rare, but unavoidable with the reputation point system in use.

Since answers must be backed with references and/or personal experiences, it won't hurt if we **increase the number of minimum characters required**.

> If we want this site to be taken seriously we have to act responsibly and show that we know what we're talking about.

That's an interesting point. IMHO, this community should be taken for what it is, no more, no less. Which doesn't mean it shouldn't work to improve.

Comment: Is the better question also "how do we educate the community to the value of longer, more detailed answers?"

Comment: @Jon Hopkins: In my book, education won't work. People that don't want to be *educated* that way will simply leave. The effects of the education process (members behavior match rules) will therefore be an illusion. It will cost us the diversity that makes this community valuable. Maybe it's the desirable effect: cutting down the community until most of the members match an idealistic profile. In that case, it's not natural selection anymore.

Comment: I don't think that "rallying the troops" necessarily constitutes a refusal to accept the community for what it is. I believe that, as Jon has pointed out, there's plenty of evidence that there's a significant and perhaps growing element of the community which values in-depth dialogue as opposed to shallow quips; however, these people often don't speak up enough or use the other tools available (downvotes, flags, etc.) to make their voices heard.

Comment: @Aaronaught: sorry for my ignorance, but what does shallow quips means?

Comment: Sorry, I forget that not everyone here is from the UK/US.  A *quip* is a short statement intended to demonstrate humour or cleverness.  A *shallow* quip, by extension, is one that *doesn't* demonstrate any genuine comprehension or attempt to educate others.  Quips are easily upvoted because they're easy to agree with; however, votes are supposed to be a measure of quality, not agreement.

Comment: @Aaronaught: I see the problem. Maybe the ultimate solution would be to drop the reputation system completely. An answer would get votes based on its quality (according the community), questions would be neutral, and members would get no points, just a name and followers. Like Quora.

Comment: @Pierre 303 As crazy as that sounds, I'm willing to listen.  But how exactly would that solve anything? Voters would still vote as they do now (simple agreement), and answerers would likely not be less willing to post these short non-answers.  In fact, those types of answers might *increase*.

Comment: @Renesis: honesly I don't know. What I see is that Quora is crowded by a-players.

Comment: I never use Quora (or Facebook) so I can't comment on which A-listers frequent it or exactly what they contribute.  However, if Quora employs the same type of *opt-in* system that Facebook does, then I would assume that to be a major part of the reason for its apparent popularity. Many folks in the upper echelons have gotten tired of all the noise and prefer to just tune into the people they care about (much like twitter or Facebook proper). I doubt that the existence or non-existence of reputation has much to do with it; personally, I could take it or leave it on a site like this.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't believe that this answer is of any use on the site:

I disagree. What you're talking about are pat answers. They're short, direct, to-the-point, usually quite correct. But *incomplete*. They impart knowledge (do X, don't do Y, etc), but they don't provide *wisdom* (why should I do X, why shouldn't I do Y).

Some people need pat answers. Some people aren't ready to know the truth. Some people aren't ready to know everything about everything. A simple shove down the proper path, feeding on the accumulated knowledge of others, is sufficient to their needs.

Take this as an example. I know nothing about password security; I do entirely different kinds of programming. Seeing this question answered with a header-sized NO, coupled with lots of upvoting, is enough to tell me that it's probably not a good idea. I don't need a 30 paragraph dissertation that ritualistically vivisects every argument for restricting passwords. I just need to know if I should.

Now, that doesn't mean I think the dissertation shouldn't exist. But the fact is that some people don't need or want it.

That being said, the answer itself isn't the problem, is it? If it were a bad answer, it would be downvoted and that would be that. The problem is that the voting system is *promoting* the pat answer.

I believe that this comes from one simple fact: what does it mean to upvote something?

A lot of forums, YouTube, etc, have voting systems for comments. Thumbs up for "liked it!", thumbs down for "hated it!". Democracy only works when everyone is saying the same thing with a vote.

I guarantee you that most of those who voted for it were thinking, "Yes, he's right." They weren't taking a considered and reasoned stand on how useful his answer was in a broad sense. They saw the answer, agreed with it, maybe chucked at the bluntness of it, and voted it up. Because they liked it and it was correct.

That's how voting works. Not everyone thinks that their vote means "this was a reply that will be a font of thoughtful and insightful knowledge for any passersby." They simply thought, "he's right, and that's funny."

So until you can find a way to make everyone use their vote to mean "thoughtful and considered" rather than "correct and liked it," then this will continue to happen.

Comment: Perfect answer. Hence the titling of the voting-links “useful” and “not useful” and not in-/correct. Maybe that fact should be promoted. A almost transparent text above the icons which become more visible on hover?

Answer (score -1):

**No, but there's (probably) nothing we can do about it.**

The (voting) community has grown as a function of time and, unfortunately, the people participating in programmers.SE are more prone to being careless and apathetic. Over time I have been here, the quality of questions and answers has diminished noticeably (and I'm fairly certain it doesn't have anything to me getting bored of this site).

In order to have your answer up-voted a lot, you write an answer that:

- People *want* to hear.
- Use very casual and simple English.

This works because all the people that don't see quality as important will *like* the answer for one stupid reason or another. The quality is continue to drop here and it is a shame. A lot of the smart and experienced users will move on and a lot of them already have.